# Can we have dark links back on mobile?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mobile-web

I like the toned down theme on mobile devices, but the recent change to blue links is uncomfortable for me. I have been trying to adjust, and I know it's ether for usability, but I liked it when the links were dark. Can I *please* have my dark links back, or at least the option to choose?

(Actually, I think the mobile sites need a new theme altogether and I'm willing to help.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question was asked before the current mobile theme (as of Oct 2011) and the feature request is now obsolete. If a moderator can, mark as status-complete.